# How can detect last retry in Spring retry?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using Spring-retry-1.3.4, i want to detect the event before the last retry and log it.
Is there a way? I think I can use RetryListener, but I can't. RetryListener does not have RetryPolicy information, so maxAttempts cannot be inquired. I think I should use another method other than RetryListener. Is there any other way?

#### TestService.java

```java
@Retryable(
            value = {Exception.class},
            maxAttempts = 2
    )
    public void test1() {
    }

    @Retryable(
            value = {Exception.class},
            maxAttempts = 3
    )
    public void test2() {
    }

    @Retryable(
            value = {Exception.class},
            maxAttempts = 4
    )
    public void test3() {
    }
```

#### MyRetryListener.java

```java
public class MyListener implements RetryListener {
...
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(
            final RetryContext context,
            final RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
            final Throwable throwable
    ) {
        if (getMaxAttemps() == context.getRetryCount()) {
            log.error("error");
        }
    }
    
    private int getMaxAttemps() {
        ???
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the same question that was asked [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/discussions/362); there is no built-in mechanism to support that but I provided a couple of work arounds in my answer to that Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the close callback in the listener.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#listeners):

> The open and **close** callbacks come before and after the entire
> retry in the simplest case...
>
> ... Note that when there is more than one listener, they are in a
> list, so there is an order. In this case, open is called in the same
> order, while onSuccess, onError, and close are called in reverse
> order.

Here you can fins an example that you can use as a guide in order to implement your code:

```
public class DefaultListenerSupport extends RetryListenerSupport {
    
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context,
      RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        logger.info("onClose");
        ...
        super.close(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context,
      RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        logger.info("onError"); 
        ...
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context,
      RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        logger.info("onOpen");
        ...
        return super.open(context, callback);
    }
}
```